# I wanna get the row ,which the sum of its elements are the highest , of any matrix at the first row but I can't find where is the problem in my code

Tags: c

I wanna get the row ,which the sum of its elements are the highest , of any matrix at the first row but I can't find where is the problem in my code , Can someone help me find the problem in a case like this :

Input

```
5 3
-619 371 -961 
-748 -130 -206 
-851 -127 743 
682 378 -849 
841 966 -868
```

my output :

```
-851 -127 743 
-748 -130 -206 
-619 371 -961 
682 378 -849 
841 966 -868
```

and the right one :

```
841 966 -868 
-748 -130 -206 
-851 -127 743 
682 378 -849 
-619 371 -961
```

The Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j,sum,max=0;
    printf("Enter # of Rows:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter # of Columns:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix:\n");
    int a[n][m];
// reading the matrix from the user
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
// printing the entered matrix
    printf("The Matrix =\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
// getting the sum of each row
    int x[n],z=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            sum = sum + a[i][j];
        }
        x[i] = sum;
    }
//getting the row which have the maximum sum
    x[0] = max;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (x[i] > max) {
            max = x[i];
            z=z+1;
        }
    }
// swapping the highest row with the first row
    int temp;
    for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
        temp = a[0][j];
        a[0][j] = a[z][j];
        a[z][j] = temp;
    }
// printing the new matrix with the highest sum row at the first
    printf ("The New Matrix = \n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Can someone help me find the problem". It might be better for you if we help you find it yourself. Have you run your program in a debugger and/or added more debug print statements? There are many debugging steps that can be taken before asking Stackoverflow to find the problem for you. Even if you can't find the exact problem, effective debugging should help you narrow down the problem. Then you can share those findings with us here.

Comment: This may also help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `x[0] = max;` - look closely at your code. Where was `max` ever set to *anything* besides its initial value of zero ? I suspect that line should be `max = x[0];` Also, `z=z+1;` i suspect should be `z = i;`

Comment: Helpful to print the `x` array and see the sums you rely on

Comment: When finding the row with the largest row sum, you need to record both the value of the sum (which you are doing) and the row number (which you are not obviously doing).  I'm not sure where else there are problems.  The `z = z + 1;` in the 'find largest sum' loop is puzzling too — I'm not clear what it's supposed to do.  It might be meant to be tracking the row number, but in that case you need `z = i;` and not an increment.

Comment: Also, the required output does not swap the old row 0 with the row with the maximal row sum.  It shifts everything down — the old row 0 moves to row 1, etc.  That requires careful coding, of course.